# How to set default route?

Tags: clojure

Using `compojure` how to set default route, e.g.

```
(defroutes app
  (GET '/api/user/:id/' [] show-user)
  (default-handler render-template)) ; this is what I want
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? I'm aware with `not-found`, but it give me 404 http status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply set a handler to `/`:

```
(defroutes app
  (GET "/api/user/:id/" [] show-user)
  (GET "/" render-template))
```

Or if you want to default any HTTP verb:

```
(defroutes app
  (GET "/api/user/:id/" [] show-user)
  (ANY "/" render-template))
```

Compojure routes match top to bottom so anything that hasn't been matched will fall back to your `/` handler.

Comment: I don't think this is true any more.  I think you need (ANY "*" render-template).